# Moving fonts to preload issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, fonts

I am using the lighthouse from chrome and I am getting the following:
[image]

I have 3 fonts from the core of Magento and I would like them to move it in my `default_head_blocks.xml` with:

```
<head>
    <font src="fonts/{FONT 1}.woff"/>
    <font src="fonts/{FONT 2}.woff"/>
    <font src="fonts/{FONT 2}.woff"/>
</head>
```

The thing is that I don't know how to remove it from core and preload it via using the `<font>`, like [HERE](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.6/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml#L11-L15). Do you have any suggestion how should I achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find them in the _typography.less and default_head_blocks.xml of the parent themes,
you an apply XML remove as remove src="fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2" or overwrite less file in your theme